# Python есть в PATH но не запускается из cmd

Tags: python, windows-10, path

Установил Python для Visual Studio 2019. Хочу также работать с ним из cmd. Добавил путь к папке, содержащей `python.exe` в переменную `Path`. Однако при перезапуске cmd и введении `python` снова появляется приглашение ко вводу, а Windows запускает свой магазин приложений и предлагает скачать Python.

Работаю на Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В новой версии Windows 10 (1903) в папку `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` разработчики поместили заглушки `python.exe`, `python3.exe` и т.д. При обращении к этим заглушкам открывается магазин Microsoft Store.

Путь к этой папке прописан почти в самом начале переменной `PATH` пользователя и добавляется к системному `PATH`. Если добавить новый путь к файлу `python.exe` в системный `PATH` то это поможет решить проблему, хотя могут возникнуть сложности при смене пользователя, когда установка была произведена в локальную папку. В этом случае предпочтительно поместить новый путь в начало пользовательского `PATH`, а не в конец, как часто происходит.

**PS**. Кардинальный способ решить эту проблему:
Параметры > Приложения и возможности > Псевдонимы выполнения приложения > отключить все опции.

[image: Псевдонимы выполнения приложения]

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился. Вот в чём была проблема: я недавно перешёл на Windows 10 c 7ой и потому не знал, что там есть **два разных Path** – системный и пользовательский. Нетрудно догадаться, что путь к Python я добавил как раз в пользовательский, а не в системный, окно для редактирования которого, к слову, находится чуть ниже.

После добавления пути в тот `Path`,  который находится в списке **системных** переменных среды, всё заработало.

Comment: При поиске системный и пользовательский path'ы складываются. Это разделение используется скорее для более удобной настройки пользователя и разделения прав.